# Content type export with drupal console not working

Tags: console

I have a content type called slider as the image below shows:

[image]

I tried the following to export the content-type:

```
drupal config:export:content:type slider
```

when I enter the command, I am prompted to type a module name, which doesn't sound right.

```
Enter the module name [admin_toolbar]:
```

How can I export a specific content type using the drupal console?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal console will create a new module for you and export the content type as configuration in new module under config folder. 
Eg.  drupal config:export:content:type slider \
--module="new_module"

Answer (score 0):

Drupal console `config:export:content:type` is to

> Export a specific content type and their fields.

and required 4 arguments:

1. **--module** : The Module name where config will exported.
2. **--optional-config** : Export content type as an optional YAML configuration in your module.
3. **--remove-uuid** : If set, the configuration will be exported without uuid key.
4. **--remove-config-hash** If set, the configuration will be exported without the default site hash key.

So you can execute it like :

```
drupal config:export:content:type article \
--module="YOURMODULE" \
--optional-config -y \
--remove-uuid -n \
--remove-config-hash -y
```

**-y** to set value of argument to **yes**
**-n** to set value of argument to **no**

for more info check [config:export:content:type documentation page](https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/en/commands/config-export-content-type.html)